# Load Jquery before angular js

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm using bower to download UI dependencies and Grunt to build UI.
I'm using grunt's wiredep to inject bower packages into index.html file automatically.

Here it injects JQuery after angular js, which prevents me from using all functionalities of JQuery.

How can i load jquery before angular js, so that i can use all jquery's functionalities without breaking my angular js app.

Thanks
Satish Lakhani

Comment: Can you add wiredep code here

Comment: Hi Anil, Below is my wiredep code.

`wiredep: {
      app: {
        src       : ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: /\.\.\//
      }
    },`

Thanks

Comment: How you are injecting jquery and angular js files

Comment: '<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->'

Here, if i manually change the order (which is first jquery and then angular) then grunt build automatically changes order (which loads angular before jquery).

Comment: Can add `vendor.js` code. Actually it should be jquery first, next angular but in code angular is loading first

Comment: Hi Anil,

I'm not getting what you are saying, can you please elaborate it more?
Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131472/discussion-between-anil-talla-and-satish-lakhani).

Comment: Hi Anil,
Sorry, i was away from this conversation
so couldn't reply on time
& Regarding dependency injection, i'm saying that. 

If i add jquery before angular & then while building code, Grunt's wiredep task automatically changes order of jquery (first angular and then jquery). 

If i comment that wiredep task of grunt, then while building code it doesn't changes the order (takes same as i placed in index.html file).

Means, wiredp task is automatically changes order of jquery & angular js..

What can be reason here?

Thanks

Comment: May be order of letters, Angular Start with A, iQuery start with J... In alphabetical order A comes before J. Can you try rename the file names.. This is just guesses.

Comment: Hi Anil, Thanks for suggestion, but this can not be the case as bootstrap related files are injected after jquery. As per you if its alphabetical order than bootstrap dependency should be injected after angularjs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to this, thought to post here, which may help some one.

Resolved this by using "grunt-wiredep": "^1.9.0".
This changed the order as per my requirement (first jquery and then angular).

Thanks
Satish Lakhani

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for doing dependency management at runtime. I've found it by far the most complete framework. Additionally it also promotes modular programming using [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) and it works with even non-amd libs by using shim.